# Проверка на наличие элемента на странице, jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, сравнение

В процессе выполнения функции следующим образом создается кнопка:

```
$('#score').append('<input id="newTry" type="button" value="Try again?"/>');
```

Необходимо, чтобы при повторном выполнении функции, инициируемом нажатием на кнопку, она не создавалась снова на этом моменте выполнения. Каким образом можно установить проверку на наличие подобного элемента на странице?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Проверку можно сделать по .length - количество найденных элементов. Если 0 (false) тогда создавать:

```js
function createButton(){
  console.log($('#newTry').length);
  if(!$('#newTry').length) $('#score').append('<input id="newTry" type="button" value="Try again?"/>');
  
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="score"></div>
<button onclick="createButton()">Create Button</button>
```

Comment: Большое спасибо за идею с if(!$('#newTry').length), обошлась только этой строкой!